# Why don't I get any response from rest request

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, httpclient

I'm trying to make a request to a rest api.

My problem is, that nothing happens I seams not to be executed at all.

I get no errors and no response at all.

Please take a look at my code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace RescoTrello
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = "http://example.com";
                var userName = "xxxx";
            var passWord = "yyyy";
            var credentials = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord));

            var client = new HttpClient(); // ideally this would be created from IHttpClientFactory
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", credentials);

            var jsonString = "{'Journal': 'Standard', 'Item':'23396', 'Qty':4 }";
            request.Content = JsonContent.Create(jsonString);

            var response = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            });
            Console.WriteLine(response.Status);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't build as posted. But your likely problem is that the application exits before your exchange with the server is completed. You would need to `await Task.Run(...)`, and that introduces other changes you need to make.

Comment: Try adding the line `response.Wait()` at the end.